# Error Code 1305. FUNCTION does not exist (MySQL Workbench 8.0.17)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, regexp-replace

I need to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` function in MySQL Workbench 8.0.17.

However, even tutorial example like:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('a b c', 'b', 'X');
```

Returns an error with the following description:

```
Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION my_schema.REGEXP_REPLACE does not exist
```

Same for other REGEXP functions as well.
Maybe the problem is in `my_schema`?
I am a new SQL user, so I cannot identify the problem.

Please help me solve the issue.
It will be much appreciated.

Comment: May be you have to do this: GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION

Comment: What is the server version? Find out with `SELECT version();`.

Comment: Currently you are using MySQL Version 8-(less than 8). That's why you are facing issue. If MySQL workbench is 8, it doesn't mean that your server is 8. So it will not work in your case.

Comment: @James, could be. how should I check that?

Comment: @stickybit, SELECT version(); returns an error:
Error Code: 2005 Unknown MySQL server host 'hostname' (2)

Comment: see comment(2) given my @stickybit